# Adding a string every time $() selects something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, web-scraping

I was working on web scraping with puppeteer on [this Italian betting site](https://www.sisal.it/scommesse-matchpoint?filtro=0&schede=man:1:21:80:18397), I want to select the div which contains the two teams name, making part of the game. So I did this:

```
let matches = $('span.AvvenimentoDescription-rieyuj-0').text();
console.log(matches)
```

and it returned me this:

```
'Bologna - BresciaCagliari - ParmaSassuolo - RomaJuventus - FiorentinaAtalanta - GenoaLazio - SpalMilan - Hellas VeronaLecce - TorinoUdinese - InterSampdoria - Napoli'
```

As you can see the matches are next to each other:

```
'Bologna - BresciaCagliari - Parma...'
```

I want it to be:

```
'Bologna - Brescia Cagliari - Parma...'
```

or even better

```
`'Bologna - Brescia,Cagliari - Parma...`
```

So, is there a way to  add a space or a comma every times that $() selects something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because when you invoke `text()` on a jQuery object targeting multiple elements jQuery will automatically concatenate their values, hence no spaces between values.

To better way to approach this would be to use `map()` to create an array of the values. Then you can `join()` this array to form a string in whatever format you need. Here's an example which separates the values by a comma:

```
let matches = $('span.AvvenimentoDescription-rieyuj-0').map((i, el) => el.textContent.trim()).get();
let output = matches.join(', ');
console.log(output);
```